# SPI Chip Select (CS) Control?

Tags: spi, driver

I am working with spidev on my RPi4 project and I have noticed that there is a significant delay caused by the CS signal. I am using the hardware CS pin (CE0, pin header 24) to drive the CS signal for my SPI device. See below for an example of the behavior I am seeing when I look at the SPI signals with a logic analyzer.

The delay between CS toggles seems to be related to the SPI clock speed I select. I have confirmed that the SPI signal is truly at the clock speeds shown, and that the data is being successfully written to my SPI device. It is just being written slowly.

[image: CS behavior at 20 MHz]

[image: CS behavior at 50 MHz]

This kind of behavior has been [documented](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90992/how-to-speed-up-spi-chip-select-transition-using-spidev) before, and it seems to be the default behavior of spidev

After some [reading](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#serial-peripheral-interface-spi), it looks like the kernel is using software GPIO control instead of the SPI peripheral to toggle the CS signal:

> The driver does not make use of the hardware chip select lines because
> of some limitations - instead it can use an arbitrary number of GPIOs
> as software/GPIO chip selects.

My questions are the following:

1. Is there a way to quickly enable hardware CS control with the existing SPI drivers, or do I have to create my own kernel driver for doing this?
2. In the documentation, what exactly does “some limitations” mean?
3. Why were things implemented this way?

I have been unable to find a meaningful answer to any of these questions. It does seem that a common approach is to create an application-specific SPI kernel driver. For most cases, having the flexibility of choosing any GPIO for CS is probably more important than having precise timing. However, this delay can become appreciable as the number of writes increases. I first noticed this issue when changing my SPI clock from 20 to 50 MHz resulted in negligible performance improvements (in terms of overall write time for a series of writes to my SPI device).